# Peugeot 307 central locking only works with remote key

Tags: central-locking, peugeot-307

I'm the lucky owner of a 2007 Peugeot 307.

It is born with central locking. However it only works using the remote. So if I use the key directly in the lock cylinder (the only lock on the car is in the driver side front door) then it opens the door, but the central locking is not activated. What could be wrong, I have no clue?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm reading here, you are expecting the key to automatically lock all the doors for you when you lock the driver's door? Have you tried turning the key a second time?

Comment: Hi! Good idea! Just went out in the driveway and tried it out. Unfortunately, no luck. The only door that locks/unlocks is the driver door it self. None of the others respond. It doesn't sound like the central lock kicks in at all

Comment: Second thing to try is to turn and hold in the lock position. One other thought ... are you sure this is irregular behavior?

Comment: @TerryGould as stated in the question, the only lock on the entire car is in the driver side front door unfortunately.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Yes, I'm sure. The user manual states that the lock can be used equally to the remote for locking/unlocking and "superlocking" the car. Also just noted a thing in the manual that caught my attention. It says in the manual, that the central locking does not work if one of the doors are not closed. Maybe it's a door sensor problem? I'm puzzled though since the remote still works as it should every time.

Comment: If the key is supposed to activate the central locking system, there's a microswitch in the door latch, and that can break/wear out.

Comment: @JPhi1618 So what exactly would need change? Have a link for the spare part?

Comment: Sorry, I was just being general.  I took apart the doors on a VW a few times, but there are no Peugeots here in the US for me to molest.